# Manipulating integral with u substitution

Tags: calculus

I have one of those stupid homework questions that is obscure and not examples given.

$f$ is a continuous function and these values are known:

$$\int_0^1 f(x) dx = 5$$

$$\int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx = 3$$

$$\int_0^2 f(x)dx = 8$$

$$\int_0^4 f(x)dx = 11$$

Evaluate:

$$\int_2^3 x f(8-x^2) dx$$

I know that I should use u substitution because that is what the worksheet says. Ok no thinking about it, just do it. That is what math is all about.

$u = 8-x^2$

$du = -2x dx$

$dx = \frac{-1}{2x}du$

$$\frac{-1}{2} \int_4^{-1} f(u)du$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^4 f(u)du$$

What good does this do me? I am stuck, I have $f(u)$ not $f(x)$ and I have done nothing because I can reintroduce $x$ but then I get what I just had.

Comment: Presumably you should have $8-x^2$ in the integral after the 'Evaluate'? Also, you have $\int_{-1}^4 = \int_{-1}^1-\int_0^1+\int_0^4$. And the variable inside the integral is a 'dummy' variable, it doesn't matter whether it is $x$ or $t$ or $u$...

Comment: But I have changed the function so how can it have the same value?

Comment: What function have you changed?

Comment: $\int f(u)du = \int f(x)dx=\int f(\textrm{banana})d\textrm{banana}$.

Comment: And that is true because the interval changes?

Comment: There is no need for those lousy comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing fine, but I will compute separately. Let $u=8-x^2$. Then $-2x\,dx=du$, so $x\,dx=-\frac{1}{2}\,du$. Substitute. We get
$$\int_{x=2}^3 xf(8-x^2)\,dx=\int_{u=4}^{-1} -\frac{1}{2}f(u)\,du$$
The integral on the right is running the wrong way. We can change the order by changing the sign, and find that we want
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{u=-1}^4 f(u)\,du.$$
Note that the variable of integration in a definite integral is a **dummy** variable, we can replace it by any other letter. The letter $x$ sounds good, we want
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^4 f(x)\,dx.$$

From the first two items of information we were given, we can find the integral from $-1$ to $0$. For 
$$\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx=\int_{-1}^0 f(x)\,dx+\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx.$$
We know two of these items, so we know the third, and find that 
$$\int_{-1}^0f(x)\,dx=3-5=-2.$$

We have also been told the integral from $0$ to $4$, plus a third useless fact. So now we can finish.

Comment: I just did it with the help of copper.hat's suggestion and I think the answer is 9/2.

Comment: Yes, it is $\frac{1}{2}(11+(-2))$.